# Concatenate problem creating links in excel

Tags: excel

I have a workbook for each week that contains all the time sheet data for the week and totals. I have created a formula that concatenates a series of strings to create a link to the cell i want to use:

```
="='D:\Dropbox (DRYBSMT)\~Employee Information\Payroll Archive\2018 Archive\[Field - PP "&IF($N$4<10,"0"&$N$4,$N$4)&".xlsx]Calculator'!$X"&O15
```

This works fine and creates the link I need.  I understand that this type of dynamic link would have to have the target file open in order to pull the data out. To avoid this and allow the data to be pulled even if the target file is closed, I need to type the link directly into the cell:

```
='D:\Dropbox (DRYBSMT)\~Employee Information\Payroll Archive\2018 Archive\[Field - PP 01.xlsx]Calculator'!$X29
```

This is the result of the original formula. I can copy this to another cell using 'Paste Values' and I now have the cell I need. I have a long column of 60-70 of these links created and copied.

The destination cell is formatted as *general* and not *text*, so the link should work.
Here is the problem:  I have to manually click inside the formula bar and hit enter for it to calculate - on each cell.  Otherwise it just shows it as copied text. I have tried changing around the formatting and then switching it back to general as well as highlighting and clicking 'calculate now'.

Any ideas on how to make it calculate when I copy it?

Comment: Are you saying this functions properly when the referenced file is open?  Values from linked workbooks don't just "disappear" when the file closes.

Comment: If I construct a reference to a workbook that is closed, the reference will not work unless the reference book is open. From my understanding and small amount of experience, a typed reference will work on a closed workbook but a reference that is generated by a formula will not work on a closed workbook but only if it is open.

Comment: A typed full directory listing like 'c:\abc\etc. including the sheet name and the cell like I have listed in the original question.  @Curtis000 has offered a solution that's works well for me.  I use Dropbox and the only caveat if the file is shared, they have to have the same path and drive letter on their computer or it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try highlighting the whole column and running the 'text to columns' tool.  Use the 'delimited' option, and uncheck all of the 'delimiters' options.  Press finish, and it should remove the formatting issue.

You basically just want run the text to columns tool to remove formatting, but not actually enter any criteria that your formula gets split up into different columns.

Comment: This worked great and will save me so many headaches and so much time!  So thank you so much. So long.